# How to I assign a value to a raw pointer at the module level in Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, variable-assignment, raw-pointer

If I have a raw pointer that is defined at the module level, how do I assign another value to it?

```
struct SomeStruct {
    field: u8,
}

// create a module level null raw pointer
static mut MODLEVELRAWPOINTER: *mut SomeStruct = std::ptr::null_mut::<SomeStruct>();
```

Because a `static *mut SomeStruct` cannot be in a `let` binding, the only way I can think of is to use std::mem::swap.

**UPDATE / EDIT**
Thanks to [@Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) for his answer!

```
struct SomeStruct {
    field: u8,
}

// create a module level null raw pointer
static mut MODLEVELRAWPOINTER: *mut SomeStruct = std::ptr::null_mut::<SomeStruct>();

fn main() {
    let mut x = SomeStruct { field: 42 };
    unsafe {
        MODLEVELRAWPOINTER = &mut x as *mut _;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mutating a static value always requires unsafe code, but other than that you just assign to it, `MODLEVELRAWPOINTER = ...`.

Comment: Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5aa8ce6fb7789750248198065699cf12

Comment: I should also mention that a mutable static variable containing a raw pointer isn't what you want. Most likely there are safer, more convenient options for your use case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for answering my question. Can you please offer an explanation to why and how the `_` is there in the line `MODLEVELRAWPOINTER = &mut x as *mut _;`? Thank you.

Comment: The underscore asks the compiler to infer the type. You could be explicit and write `as *mut SomeStruct` instead, or you could be less explicit and write `as _`. This work because the compiler knows the type of `MODLEVELRAWPOINTER`, so the target type of the conversion is clear. I chose `&mut x as *mut _` since I think in conveys the essence of what we are doing here – taking a reference to `x` and converting it to a raw pointer.